# Javascript - replace broken image by text (div; css class)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to replace all broken image by JS. I use this code to replace all broken images by notfound.png image.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').attr('onError', 'this.src="notfound.png"');
});
```

Anyway, I would like to replace them by a text notice instead of image. I cannot find the proper way how to do it, thank you very much for your help. JS is not my cup of coffee :(

I would like to use this for the text part:

Text to to shown...

**EDIT:**
OK, I have found this solution working fine, but doesnt accept CSS class

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.post_body img').one('error', function() {
$(this).replaceWith('<div>Image not found (error 404)</div>').addClass('error404');
});
});
</script>
```

Anyway as I wrote CSS class is not added, so this solution is not complete :(

CSS will be:

```
.error404 {
   display: block;
   color: #667d99;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 11px;
   border: 1px dotted;
   border-radius: 3px;
   padding: 5px;
   margin: 10px;
   background: #e7edf3;
   text-aling: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I have found a solution for you. I tried to use jQuery [error](https://api.jquery.com/error/) function. This one helped me:

> To replace all the missing images with another, you can update the src attribute inside the callback passed to .error(). Be sure that the replacement image exists; otherwise the error event will be triggered indefinitely.

In your example this would be the best:

```
$('img').each(function() {
    var img = $(this);

    img.error(function() {
        img.replaceWith('<div class="error404">Image not found (error 404)</div>');
    }).attr('src', img.attr('src'));
});
```

I also made a [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/qz6rs6x4/) for you, which is working great for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a text node and append it to the parent of `img`, and optionally remove `img` if needed. This code goes inside the `error` handler for `img`

```
$('img').on('error', function(){
    $(this).parent().append($('<div>Broken image</div>'));
    $(this).remove();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use javascript for this try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').attr('alt', 'Alternative text');
});
```

But the same is achievable by barebone HTML

```
<img src="path/to/image.jpg" alt="Alternative text">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the alt if an error is thrown just like you're doing with the image.

```
function imgMissing(image) {
image.onerror = "";
image.alt = "Image not Found";
return true;
}
```

The HTML:

```
    <img src="image.jpg" onerror="imgMissing(this);" >
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: OK, I have found this solution working fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.post_body img').one('error', function() {
$(this).replaceWith('<div>Image not found (error 404)</div>');
});
});
</script>
```

Anyway one more think, I need to add CSS class "error404" for this "div", how to do that in JS? Thank you very much!

CSS will be:

```
.error404 {
   display: block;
   color: #667d99;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 11px;
   border: 1px dotted;
   border-radius: 3px;
   padding: 5px;
   margin: 10px;
   background: #e7edf3;
}
```

Comment: So that code will be `$(this).replaceWith('<div>Image not found (error 404)</div>').addClass('error404');` ???

Comment: `$(this).replaceWith('<div>Image not found (error 404)</div>').addClass('error404');`

Comment: look at my answer, I found a solution for you.